# Joomla 3.x client-side form validation, overriding default error messages

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Is it possible to override default form field error message? For example (code from http://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
   document.formvalidator.setHandler('birth', function(value) {
      regex=/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
      return regex.test(value);
   });
});
```

Depending this code snippet we will get "Invalid field: FIELD_LABEL_TITLE" error message. But how to set default message like "Invalid birth field: Birth date must match following format: Year-month-day".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is possible for server-side validation by setting a "message" attribute to the jForm field for client-side validation Joomla will show a fixed error message in the format:

```
Invalid field: <label-name>
```

You can either remove the "required" class from your submit button or completely override Joomla's client-side validation with another javascript/jQuery validation plugin.

In the first case invalid fields should still show as invalid "onChange" but wont validate the form on client-side before submitting it to the server. Therefore, make sure that you have set your server-side validation properly which you should have done anyway.